# Make Group in Group based on first Group in crystal report

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have a stored procedure that show a record like below.

```
AccountID     AccountName               Amount     ParentAccountID     ParentAccountName
ABI01         Cost of infrastructure A  1077665.4  INF                 Infrastructure
ABI02         Cost of infrastructure B  42000      INF                 Infrastructure
ABM01         Cost of Maintenance A     465900     MTN                 MAINTENANCE
ABM02         Cost of Maintenance B     3450000    MTN                 MAINTENANCE
ABO01         Cost of Operational A     110500     ABM02               Cost of Maintenance B
```

I want a crystal report to showing result like this:

```
INF : Infrastructure

    ABI01   Cost of infrastructure A   1077665

    ABI02   Cost of infrastructure B   42000

MTN : Maintenance

    ABM01   Cost of Maintenance A   465900

    ABM02   Cost of Maintenance B   3450000

        ABO01   Cost of Operational A   110500
```

Is it possible to be made? Thanks for the help.. btw how to make the table looks good in SO?

Answer (score 0):

Considering the result set you have shown, I believe you can achieve the requirement by just putting in a group **ParentAccountID** in crystal reports. In group header you can add column **PArentAccountname** column in front of Group name column. Doing this will give you desired output. I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the reply.. I've tried it before but It didn't give the result I wanted. the result will look like this :

INF : Infrastructure

    ABI01   Cost of infrastructure A   1077665

    ABI02   Cost of infrastructure B   42000

MTN : Maintenance

    ABM01   Cost of Maintenance A   465900

    ABM02   Cost of Maintenance B   3450000

ABM02  : Cost of Maintenance B    
    
    ABO01   Cost of Operational A   110500

Comment: I fromatted the output present in your comment and I am sseing the same as the one you have asked for in your question. Am I missing something?